# Data duplication in horizontal listView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am working on a demo in that i have used a horizontal listView for displaying some images and texts ,I have done it successfully but my issue is at time when images are loading it displays same image twice(in two listitems).All times my last image is showing in my 4th listitem of my horizontal ListView in android,Can anybody help me to fix this issue?my adapter is as below;

```
public class RecentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Post> popularAry;

    Viewholder localViewholder = null;
    private Context mContext;
    String resnID, reson;
    Intent i;

    public RecentAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<Post> recentAry) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.popularAry = recentAry;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return this.popularAry.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }
    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }
    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
            ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");

        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.raw_recent, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.tv_name = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_name));
            localViewholder.tv_hrt = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_hrt));
            localViewholder.tv_cmnt = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_cmnt));
            localViewholder.iv_pic = ((ImageView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewGridPostImage));
            localViewholder.rl_det = (RelativeLayout)paramView.
                    findViewById(R.id.rl_det);
            localViewholder.iv_hrt = ((Button) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_hrt));
            localViewholder.iv_cmnt = ((ImageView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_cmnt));

//          localViewholder.iv_hrt =  ((ImageView) paramView
//                  .findViewById(R.id.imageViewGridPostImage));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }
        localViewholder.tv_name.setText(popularAry.get(paramInt).postTitle);
        localViewholder.tv_hrt.setText((popularAry.get(paramInt).postLikesCount)+"");
        localViewholder.tv_cmnt.setText((popularAry.get(paramInt).postCommentsCount) + "");

        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(localViewholder.iv_pic, popularAry.get(paramInt).postImagePath, null, 3600000);

        if(paramInt == 7){
            localViewholder.iv_pic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_morepost);
        }

        if (popularAry.get(paramInt).likedThisPost) {
            localViewholder.iv_hrt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_likes);

        } else {
            localViewholder.iv_hrt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_liked);
//          localViewholder.iv_hrt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
//                  R.drawable.btn_liked, 0, 0, 0);
        }


    return paramView;
    }

    static class Viewholder {
    TextView tv_name;
        ImageView iv_pic,iv_cmnt;
        Button iv_hrt;

        TextView tv_hrt,tv_cmnt;
        RelativeLayout rl_det;

    }

}
```

**Horizontal ListView**

```
public class HorizontialListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

    public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
    protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
    protected int mCurrentX;
    protected int mNextX;
    private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
    protected Scroller mScroller;
    private GestureDetector mGesture;
    private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
    private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;


    public HorizontialListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        mLeftViewIndex = -1;
        mRightViewIndex = 0;
        mDisplayOffset = 0;
        mCurrentX = 0;
        mNextX = 0;
        mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        mOnItemSelected = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
        mOnItemClicked = listener;
    }

    private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onInvalidated();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
        //TODO: implement
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if(mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        //TODO: implement
    }

    private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
        LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
        if(params == null) {
            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        }

        addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
        child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if(mAdapter == null){
            return;
        }

        if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
            int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
            mNextX = scrollx;
        }

        if(mNextX < 0){
            mNextX = 0;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }
        if(mNextX > mMaxX) {
            mNextX = mMaxX;
            mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        }

        int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

        removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
        fillList(dx);
        positionItems(dx);

        mCurrentX = mNextX;

        if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
            post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    requestLayout();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void fillList(final int dx) {
        int edge = 0;
        View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        if(child != null) {
            edge = child.getRight();
        }
        fillListRight(edge, dx);

        edge = 0;
        child = getChildAt(0);
        if(child != null) {
            edge = child.getLeft();
        }
        fillListLeft(edge, dx);


    }

    private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
        while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

            View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
            rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

            if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1){
                mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
            }
            mRightViewIndex++;
        }

    }

    private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
        while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
            View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
            addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
            leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mLeftViewIndex--;
            mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    }

    private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
        View child = getChildAt(0);
        while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
            mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mLeftViewIndex++;
            child = getChildAt(0);

        }

        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
            mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
            removeViewInLayout(child);
            mRightViewIndex--;
            child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
        }
    }

    private void positionItems(final int dx) {
        if(getChildCount() > 0){
            mDisplayOffset += dx;
            int left = mDisplayOffset;
            for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
                left += childWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
        mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean handled = mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return handled;
    }

    protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
        synchronized(HorizontialListView.this){
            mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }

    protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
        return true;
    }

    private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return HorizontialListView.this.onDown(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return HorizontialListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

            synchronized(HorizontialListView.this){
                mNextX += (int)distanceX;
            }
            requestLayout();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Rect viewRect = new Rect();
            for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                int left = child.getLeft();
                int right = child.getRight();
                int top = child.getTop();
                int bottom = child.getBottom();
                viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
                if(viewRect.contains((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY())){
                    if(mOnItemClicked != null){
                        mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontialListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, 0);
                    }
                    if(mOnItemSelected != null){
                        mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontialListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, 0);
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

            };

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RecycleView instead of ListView, and it's save a lot of your time. If you see Google IO this year, android team recommends "forget" painful List view. Look like problem in your holder binding logic. In case of Recycle view work with binding more comfortable, and code refactoring don take a lot of time.

Android developer resource contain good [example](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: apreciate your suggestion,But can i do solution in this code,or is it impossible?

Comment: It possible of course, but need more code sharing from your side. I think will be better debug your problem in context of recycle view, because List view problem resolving need to much overhead code with not only your content handling but List view widget as well

Comment: Ok,but can you help me little more by providing any good demo of horizontal listView using recyleView for custom listitem?

Comment: LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

Comment: Just setup layout manager for recycle view during creation. And your recycle view will be horizontal. And yes? example the same

Comment: can you help me to figure it out,As i am not on the way to change it to recycleView.

Comment: share your code with me on git hub or any other git service, i'll help

Comment: Hello friend,I have added required code here,I cant upload it to git ,can u help me with this.

Comment: Create git account and add your project(https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/user/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/#platform-linux)  this link will help you(choose your os)